# ORM tools with visual designer for PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, orm

I need an ORM tool with a visual designer for PHP and MySQL.

Are there any such open source/freely available solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are free tool like :
( [mysql workbench](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?153,208229,208229) + [doctrine plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-workbench-doctrine-plugin/) )

and there are paid software like 
[ormdesigner](http://www.orm-designer.com/)

and i had already seen a very interesting project : 
https://github.com/johmue/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter

it seems to be promising

Comment: Only a note, ORM Designer 3 was renamed to Skipper available here  [http://www.skipper18.com](http://www.skipper18.com)